# HTML 5 Video player not working in Firefox, No Console erros

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

The page is iframed into a Facebook page here: https://www.facebook.com/PruProtectUK/app_212796208869431

I've looked around for a fix, and originally I had the common problem content/text being passed etc so I implemented the HTAccess fix for this.

But the video still will not play in Firefox, can anybody see a reason why??

Video code:

```
<video controls="yes">
<source src="https://xxx.xxxx.co.uk/xxxx/facebook/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ChanceToRide_CustomerVersionFB3.mp4">
<a href="https://xxx.xxxx.co.uk/xxxx/facebook/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ChanceToRide_CustomerVersionFB3.mp4">Not supported</a>
</video>
```

Comment: Can you paste your video tags?

Answer (score 0):

The error I get seems self explanatory:

```
[00:47:42.932] HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource https://fapps.wrdadmin.co.uk/pruprotect/facebook/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ChanceToRide_CustomerVersionFB3.mp4 failed. @ https://fapps.wrdadmin.co.uk/pruprotect/facebook/
[00:47:42.933] All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. @ https://fapps.wrdadmin.co.uk/pruprotect/facebook/
```

If you want it to work on Firefox in anything other than Windows 7 or 8 then you'll need to transcode to another format like WebM.

Comment: Ah man really, so Firefox cannot load MP4 videos in HTML 5? I am using windows 7 and it still doesn't work!

Do you know of a WordPress plugin that will auto create/transcode the videos?